# R - sort data frame after rbind and keep NA in order

Tags: r, sorting, rbind

I have two data frames. Each has two columns. The first df has no NA values, the second df has NA values in its first column. Example:

```
> myA
     Foo Bar
1   blue   G
2  brown   I
3  black   F
4   pink   D
5  green   H
6 orange   J
7 purple   K
8    red   C
> myB
  Foo Bar
1  NA   A
2  NA   B
3  NA   E
```

I join them using rbind, as follows:

```
> newdata <- rbind(myA, myB)
> newdata
      Foo Bar
1    blue   G
2   brown   I
3   black   F
4    pink   D
5   green   H
6  orange   J
7  purple   K
8     red   C
9    <NA>   A
10   <NA>   B
11   <NA>   E
```

Now I sort that df using order on the second column and get:

```
> newSorted <- newdata[order(newdata$Bar),]
> newSorted
      Foo Bar
8     red   C
4    pink   D
3   black   F
1    blue   G
5   green   H
2   brown   I
6  orange   J
7  purple   K
9    <NA>   A
10   <NA>   B
11   <NA>   E
```

What it appears to have done is sort each original df on the second column and segmented the new df. That's not what I want to achieve. I know that order takes arguments for na.last, but the NA values are in the first column, whereas I'm asking it to sort on the second column. I want to get:

```
Foo      Bar
<NA>     A
<NA>     B
red      C
pink     D
<NA>     E
black    F
blue     G
green    H
brown    I
orange   J
purple   K
```

Please accept my apologies in advance if this request for help is not properly formatted or styled correctly. This is my first post on stackoverflow.

Any suggestions on what I may be missing or how to do this?

Comment: check if you your columns are factors.  Using character columns, I am getting the expected result.  WIth factor variables, I am able to reproduce the result you got.  So, change it to character variables.

Comment: use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when making your data frame and make sure the bar column are characters and not factors. The NAs affect the ordered of the levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are factors,  change ito characters.

```
 newdata[] <- lapply(newdata, as.character)
 newdata[order(newdata$Bar),]
        Foo Bar
  11   <NA>   A
  21   <NA>   B
  8     red   C
  4    pink   D
  31   <NA>   E
  3   black   F
  1    blue   G
  5   green   H
  2   brown   I
  6  orange   J
  7  purple   K
```

Comment: Why not just `newdata[order(as.character(newdata$Bar)), ]`? It would be a waste to turn everything to character.

Comment: Good point. In that way, `Huddo` can keep the variables as factors.